# How can I get a torrent file to download from a info hash in PHP?

Tags: php

I have alot of info hashes for torrents but cannot relate them to any such torrent file and am trying to write a PHP program that will do this for me and download the torrent file.

In a browser it is done like so with the last 40 digits being the info hash,

```
href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:7ea1b59cce1737437a66e29a2843b5ce3a0c8cd9"
```

I have tried to download the file in php like so,

```
$file = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:7ea1b59cce1737437a66e29a2843b5ce3a0c8cd9';
fopen($file, 'r');
```

But it doesn't work?? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at http://pear.php.net/package/File_Bittorrent2

Comment: Thanks will look at this and let you know :)